# How to parallelize loading data into an RDD in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I am using the MLLib library and the MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile() method. I have a file that is 10GB and cluster with 5 slaves, with 2 cores and 6 GB memory each. According to the documentation found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/api/python/pyspark.mllib.util.MLUtils-class.html), the method has the following parameters:

`loadLibSVMFile(sc, path, multiclass=False, numFeatures=-1, minPartitions=None)`

I would like to have 10 partitions and I don't know the number of features. When I run the method without specifying the minimum partitions, I get the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` as would be expected.

However, when I specify the numFeatures to be -1 as is default in the documentation, and the number to partitions to 10, based on the WebUI it does distribute the work, but after some time I get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. The rest of the code looks identical to the example code written [here.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-support-vector-machines-svms)

I am brand new to Spark so please tell me if I am making some obvious mistake. Thanks!

EDIT 2: I ran the same thing with a sample dataset that was tiny and dense, and it works fine. Seems to be a problem with the number of features?

EDIT 3:
Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
object MLLibExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext()
    //loading the RDD
    val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "s3n://file.libsvm", -1, 10)
    // Run training algorithm to build the model
    val numIterations = 10
    val model = SVMWithSGD.train(data, numIterations)
    }
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
15/07/20 20:42:43 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 35, 10.249.67.97): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS$.dot(BLAS.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS$.dot(BLAS.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.HingeGradient.compute(Gradient.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1$$anonfun$1.apply(GradientDescent.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1$$anonfun$1.apply(GradientDescent.scala:190)
```

-I have made sure the input file is correctly formatted (0/1 labels and space-delimited)

-Tried a subsample of the original file that is 10 MB

-Set both driver and executor memory

-Added this tag to my spark-submit command: --conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=6G"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83854/discussion-on-question-by-ana-how-to-parallelize-loading-data-into-an-rdd-in-spa).

Comment: Can you add the logs from the executors, It might be that an executor got an exception or was killed. And the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is because you lost an executor.